# External HDD detected but not working

Tags: windows, partitioning, external-hard-drive, disk-management, recovery

I took out an HDD from my old laptop which was working fine and never had any issues. I bought a casing for it and started using it as an external HDD. After a few months, I plugged in the HDD as an external USB device, but it didn't show up. I checked Disk Management, and it is being shown there, but I cannot do anything with it. If I select the volume and right-click on it all the options are disabled only Delete Volume is enabled. I cannot delete the volume as it has important data in it.

Is there a way to quickly recover the partition or data from that drive?

[image]

Comment: have you checked the SMART stats and run a filesystem check on the volume? especially now that its external, its more subject to improper unmounts. power failures, etc.

Comment: personally, I'd use a linux based "live cd" - linux can be more forgiving for troublesome drives (can be less forgiving too though)

Comment: The two partition seems not formatted. Before trying all kind of tools, I suggest you do a physical image backup using a tool like Macrium Reflect Free. You need another disk to do the backup. This way, you can try recovering the data and if it fails, you restore the backup and try with another tool.